# flutter error Authorization with jwt token

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart, jwt, flutter-layout

I use flutter for mobile developement application and laravel for api developement,In postman it works perfectly but I found error Authorization in Flutter.
error is return this message:

> { message : "Unauthenticated" }

code flutter:

```
    _getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    token = jsonDecode(_prefs.getString('token'));
  }
    _setHeaders() => {
    'Content-type' : 'application/json',
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer $_getToken()'
  };
```

and this is code middlware laravel:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    if ($jwt = $request->cookie('jwt')) {
        $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $jwt);
    }

    $this->authenticate($request, $guards);

    return $next($request);
}
```

how to resolve this error and thanks.

Comment: print this line: `'Authorization' : 'Bearer $_getToken()'`

Answer (score 0):

You don't return the token value from the `_getToken()` function. Therefor here you don't add the token to the headers: `'Authorization' : 'Bearer $_getToken()'`

Comment: same problem i got unauthenticated

Answer (score 0):

Your `_getToken()` should return something. Here is the example.

```
String _getToken(){
 return 'token';
}
```

If using back your function still can works. Use `token` instead of using `_getToken()` because your function doesn't return anything.

```
 'Authorization' : 'Bearer $token'
```

Comment: Same problem  i got unauthenticated